# What are the typical sources where an app Widget gets data from?

Tags: android

I am trying to digest Android App Widgets at the moment. I understand that App widgets are mini applications that reside on home screen and can display some data in supported views. What I am trying to understand is typical design pattern that goes in building app widget.

What are the typical sources where App widgets get data from? Below is my understanding and questions so far:

- Database : MainActivity gets data from network, stores in local database and then send broadcast intent to widget so that widget updates itself by fetching data from database
- Network: can widget make network call directly using Retrofit?
- Shared Preferences: is it good idea for widget to fetch small piece of info say string array from shared preferences?
- MainActivity: can MainActivity (or anyother activity class) directly set data in widget's Listview adapter?
- Intent : can i use putExtra in broadcast intent to set array of strings?

In my use-case, I get new data in mainActivity which i want to push to the widget. what's the best approach to do it?

Comment: Do you want to use Intent.putExtras inside widget class or inside mainActivity to send data to widget?

Comment: inside mainActivity to send data to widget. data is array of strings.

Comment: you don't need to use intent to send data to widget. either you can save it in shared preferences inside mainActivity or if the list is already stored in database you can just call the query to get data and use it in widget class. I am adding my code in answer where I have get data from preference and db  inside widget class.

Comment: awesome. Thanks man. One more question: after updating sharedPreference from mainActivity, I want to trigger update on the widget. I am using this code but its not updating the widget.         AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        int appWidgetIds[] = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), WidgetDataProvider.class));
        appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetIds, R.id.widget_list);

Comment: I hope the code in answer will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to get data from database , which was being update from `MainActivty`. so in order to fetch data inside widget class, I just called the query to get data from database. and I used shared preferences too , to get some data. that's not a problem. you can use shared preferences to get data.

```
public class BottleWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                            int appWidgetId) {
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.bottle_widget);

    // isUnitAdded getting value from shared pref
    boolean isUnitAdded= TinyDB.getInstance(context).getBoolean("units_added");
    if (isUnitAdded){
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent2, 0);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_root_layout_bottle, pendingIntent2);
    }
    else {
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, UnitsActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent2, 0);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_root_layout_bottle, pendingIntent2);
    }




    Constants constants = new Constants(context);

      //getting value from shared pref
    Double mTargetQuantity = Double.parseDouble(constants.getPref(Constants.DRINK_VALUE_SHARED_PREF, context));
    if (mTargetQuantity ==0)
        mTargetQuantity= Double.valueOf(100);
    // initializing database
    MyDataBase myDataBase = MyDataBase.getInstance(context);
    Calendar calendarToday = Calendar.getInstance();
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
    long millis = calendarToday.getTimeInMillis();
    String date = dateFormat.format(millis);

     // calling query to get data from database
    int mProgress = myDataBase.dailyConsumptionDao().getQuantity(date);

      // getting data from sharedpref
    String drinkUnit=constants.getPref(Constants.DRINK_UNIT_SHARED_PREF,context);
    int target= (int)Math.round(mTargetQuantity);
    int percentage= (mProgress*100)/target;
    int Icon= TinyDB.getInstance(context).getInt("icon");

    views.setImageViewResource(R.id.widget_iv_add,R.drawable.ic_add);
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.tv_total_percentage,String.valueOf(percentage)+ " %");
    views.setTextColor(R.id.tv_total_percentage, Color.WHITE);

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
    }
}

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext());
    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context.getApplicationContext(), BottleWidget.class);
    int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
    if (appWidgetIds != null && appWidgetIds.length > 0) {
        onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    }
}
```